# Errors when upgrading Vuforia in Unity from version 9 to version 10

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, unity3d-editor, unity3d-terrain

> The type or namespace name 'SmartTerrain' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> The type or namespace name 'PositionalDeviceTracker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

These errors weren't in version 9 but in version 10 they are affecting project flow please help me

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Vuforia;
public class ARManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlaneFinderBehaviour finder;
    SmartTerrain smartTerrain;
    PositionalDeviceTracker positionalDeviceTracker;
    ...........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: **These types don't exist anymore since they are not needed anymore.**

---

I would start at [Vuforia - Migration Guide for Vuforia Engine Unity Projects](https://library.vuforia.com/project-migration/how-migrate-unity-project).

In general for any software library it is not unlikely that things and the API change between major versions - indeed such a breaking change is one of the main reasons to release a new major version at all!

> This page documents the changes between Vuforia Engine version 9.8 and version 10 **as the API has fundamentally changed**. Use this overview to learn about the native changes and for migrating your existing projects to the new API.

So read up what to use instead or what changed in the API => what **you** have to change in your code to adopt - or stick to the version 9 if it worked for you and you don't need the newest features ;)

In your specific cases

> ### [Ground Plane](https://library.vuforia.com/project-migration/how-migrate-unity-project#ground-plane-1)
>
> Some more advanced Ground Plane APIs have changed. Apps that were using not just the game objects above, but additional runtime scripting APIs might have to be adapted.
>
> The Smart Terrain Tracker **has been removed**. It no longer needs to be managed manually. Consequently, checking for Ground Plane support at runtime has changed.
>
> Vuforia Engine 9.8:
>
> ```
> SmartTerrain smartTerrain = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<SmartTerrain>();
> if (smartTerrain == null)
>     Debug.Log("SmartTerrain returned null. GroundPlane not supported on this device.");
> ```
>
> Vuforia Engine 10.0:
>
> ```
> if (VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.World.AnchorsSupported == false)
>     Debug.Log("GroundPlane not supported on this device.");
> ```

and

> ### [Device Tracking](https://library.vuforia.com/project-migration/how-migrate-unity-project#device-tracking-1)
>
> Access to device tracking has been simplified and is now available
> centrally through `VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.DevicePoseBehaviour`.
>
> #### Resetting Device Tracking
>
> Vuforia Engine 9.8:
>
> ```
> var deviceTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();
> deviceTracker.Reset();
> ```
>
> Vuforia Engine 10.0:
>
> ```
> VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.DevicePoseBehaviour.Reset();
> ```
>
> #### Registering to updates to the device tracking status
>
> Vuforia Engine 9.8:
>
> ```
> private void Start()
> {
>     DeviceTrackerARController.Instance.RegisterDevicePoseStatusChangedCallback(OnDevicePoseStatusChanged);
> }
> void OnDevicePoseStatusChanged(Vuforia.TrackableBehaviour.Status status, Vuforia.TrackableBehaviour.StatusInfo statusInfo)
> {
>     Debug.Log("OnDevicePoseStatusChanged(" + status + ", " + statusInfo + ")");
>
>     …
> }
> ```
>
> Vuforia Engine 10.0:
>
> ```
> private void Start()
> {
>     VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.DevicePoseBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnDevicePoseStatusChanged; 
> }
> void OnDevicePoseStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour behaviour, TargetStatus targetStatus)
> {
>     Debug.Log("OnDevicePoseStatusChanged(" + targetStatus.Status + ", " + targetStatus.StatusInfo + ")");
> }
> ```
>
> #### Enabling and disabling Device Tracking
>
> Vuforia Engine 9.8:
>
> ```
> public void ToggleDeviceTracking(bool enableDeviceTracking)
> {
>     var posDeviceTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.InitTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();
>     if (enableDeviceTracking)
>         posDeviceTracker.Start();
>     else
>         posDeviceTracker.Stop();
> }
> ```
>
> Vuforia Engine 10.0:
>
> ```
> public void ToggleDeviceTracking(bool enableDeviceTracking)
> {
>     VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.DevicePoseBehaviour.enabled = enableDeviceTracking; 
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi, i have added the lines by editing the question, please have a look the errors are only in the declaration part not in the working part my best guess is that i am missing some kind of header or namespace file.... Kindly look at the lines and tell me what to do..

Comment: @rew did you read the answer and migration docu at all? ;) In short: **These types don't exist anymore since they are not needed anymore.** -> So what to do is: Remove those fields and refactor your code according to the linked migration documentation